# White shadow accompanying white colored text on a black background

Tags: display, external-display

So, I bought this used LCD Dell P2412H today. It shows a shadow on the right side of images and text. What's funny is it doesn't do this with black text on a white background. It would only do this with text and images on a dark background.

This monitor is connected through a VGA cable with my laptop (having an Intel HD 620 & Nvidia 930MX). I have tried adjusting, unplugging and plugging my VGA cable. The monitor also does have a DVI port, but my laptop only has a VGA port.

I don't know if it matters, but my laptop screen's native resolution is 720p while the monitor is 1080p (16:9).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot shows no shadow problem; it'd take a camera picture to see it.  It's quite possible your monitor needs adjustments; a “contrast” set too high tends to create “outlines”, for instance.  As VGA signals rely on tight clock sync, you may also have a “auto-focus” in your monitor menus (or something to that effect) to adjust the sync.

Comment: I replaced my VGA cable and that fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Please post that as an answer.